# Select ng-model not binding to ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I need to build a simple state, city, location filter using angularjs.  I just about have a working sample together, but my select won't bind to the output.  Here is the code:

http://jsbin.com/kamenoficihu/7/edit

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The groupBy in <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in stores | groupBy: 'State' | filter:{State: search.State} | orderBy:State"> appears to be causing a filtering issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key,val) in stores | groupBy: 'State' | filter:selectedState">
```

on this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key,val) in stores | filter:selectedState | groupBy: 'State'">
```

Comment: Correct.  The filter needs to go before the groupBy.  There were some other angularjs errors that jsbin was hiding (the UI was still functional), but the suggested fix wired up the filter.  Thanks!